# When hiding the child, the size of the main window changes

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a `QTabWidget` that is hidden. When I show it, the main window grows, but after hiding the `QTabWidget` again, the main window doesn't have the desired size. The `QTabWidget` is in a `QGridlayout` (the main windows layout). I’ve tried all this, one at time, but couldn't get it working:

```
def optionsView(self):
    """
    Hide or show the Tab-widget
    """
    if self.tabWidget.isVisible():
        self.tabWidget.hide()
        self.setMaximumHeight(100)
        self.gridLayout.update()
        self.update()
        self.gridLayout.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.resize(QSize(200,200))
        print self.tabWidget.geometry()
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the size of your main window? Puedes contestar en español

Comment: So, you want that your main window to be some default size (for example 200,200?), to grow when you show tabWidget, and when you hide tabWidget to go back on default size?